# FuelPHP: Pagination in Search Result

Tags: pagination, fuelphp

I am having problems with pagination. Actually, the documentation doesn't tell much on how to implement it. I have a search page that will display the search results. I want it broken down into pages, as they can compile a lot if there are a lot of data.

Following the tutorial, here is my controller (I will just paste it on pastebin for convenience):
http://pastebin.com/9yqYdPuE

Here is my View
http://pastebin.com/x5jUL5n4

And my Model
http://pastebin.com/C6fxNX5C

The pagination displays fine as you can see:
http://screencast.com/t/U7lh3UwPQH

I also routed it on router.php since it add /:number in the uri if you click two, as intended, so I add it up.

Of course, when I click it, I am just directed to a blank search page. I would think it is because the search parameters were not passed when I clicked two, as the $_POST is empty.

So what can I do to make this work? Should I change my form method to GET instead of POST? Any other things I had missed in the Model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fuel's pagination does not care $_POST parameters.

So you need to care about it by yourself.
For example, change pagination templates which post parameters with JavaScript when clicked.

Comment: I was more into storing the POST parameters, so when the user clicks on, let's say, page 2 I will just change the offset and the other settings he/she entered will be used.